# Installation failed due to: 'null':Android Studio 3.5.1 Failled in a real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk, xiaomi

I am trying to test my app on my phone **Redmi Note 7**.But once the build is successfull it is showing the installation unsuccessfull.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

OS: Windows 10

Android Studio:3.5.1

Device:Redmi Note 7

How do i fix this issue.

Comment: I had already found this page. But none helped as it used emulator. There is a comment  on apache gradle which i am using in my project. He gave a solution to change the version number which is not available. So that is why i asked this question